# Rails: nested ActiveRecord class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In my Rails app I'm loading some data from the filesystem (HTML files). But I want some ActiveRecord objects to reference this external data and link them in the db using foreign keys etc. (and also because I want them to be passed into a Ember.js app which I don't want to hack to work w/o ids).

My idea was to create a nested `IdMapping` class which would map the element names loaded from the HTML to a persistent id in the database. Everytime an element with the same name is loaded, it receives the correct id from the database via the mapping.

```
class SheetTemplate
  include ActiveModel::Model

  class IdMapping < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'sheet_template_id_mappings'
    has_one :game_system
    validates :game_system, presence: true
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :game_system }
  end

  attr_accessor :name, :author, :game_system, :boxes

end
```

Only somehow ActiveRecord doesn't like this:

```
[1] pry(main)> n = SheetTemplate::IdMapping.new
#<SheetTemplate::IdMapping:0x00000006045e38> {
                :id => nil,
    :game_system_id => nil,
              :name => nil
}
[2] pry(main)> n.game_system = gs
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `game_system_id'
from /home/marcus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@illunis/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:72:in `write_attribute'
```

This seems to work:

```
[3] pry(main)> n.game_system_id = gs.id
1
```

But saving doesn't:

```
[4] pry(main)> n.name = 'Foobar'
"Foobar"
[5] pry(main)> n.save
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SheetTemplate::IdMapping Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "sheet_template_id_mappings"  WHERE ("sheet_template_id_mappings"."name" = 'Foobar' AND "sheet_template_id_mappings"."game_system_id" = 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
false
```

Here I should probably mention that the table is empty so there's no way that the IdMapping could exist - I even double-checked using the dbconsole.

Any suggestions and ideas are welcome! :)

Comment: Why do you have `game_system_id` in your `IdMapping` model?You have `has_one` relation with `game_system`,so `GameSystem` model supposed to have `id_mapping_id`.

Comment: Good question :D Not sure why I changed it, now it works as expected - that should teach me to go to bed when tired :P

Comment: Hmm.well i will be posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your models,you have **`has_one :game_system`** in your **`IdMapping`** model,so having **`geme_system_id`** in your **`IdMapping`** model is **inappropriate** and **wrong**.

Instead you should be having **`id_mapping_id`** in **`GameSystem`** model.This should resolve the error.

Comment: Thanks, changed it to `belongs_to` (which it originally was, too). Also, after sleeping on it, I'm thinking about moving the whole template-processing to the Javascript part of the app.